# Paste Function Broken

Tags: formatting, bug

My paste function appears to be broken for my Wordpress site. I have tried on multiple computers, and browsers, and the results are the same: I cannot post anything, whether it be text, an image, or whether it is from an external source or from within the Wordpress post which I am writing.

The copy function seems to work fine; I can copy text from inside the Wordpress post.

I have tried both right clicking, ctrl+v, using the TinyMCE toolbar for Pasting. I am the Admin and owner of the blog. This is for all posts. When I make a new post, it is the same. Copy and paste still works on everything else. On comments on articles, it works. The only thing it doesn't work on is while I am writing posts. There is definitely something on the clipboard. I have tested that multiple times. Nothing works when writing a post, and it doesn't work only when writing a post.

Can anyone help me? It really would be a big help, as it is severely slowing down my writing process.

Comment: Hi, if there is something wrong with the clipboard, then your question is not related to WordPress... But try this. Open the developer's console (using F12 on firefox) and then click the Setting button (top right corner, the gear icon). Check the `Disable JavaScript` option, and see if you can paste after the page is reloaded.

Comment: @JackJohansson Hi, I tried doing this. Pasting, but unfortunately, it disables the Visual Editor and only allows me to use the HTML editor, something which I would rather not use. Also, pasting still works for the HTML editor. It's just the visual editor where it doesn't work.

Comment: There is absolutely a script blocking your paste function. Probably by one of your plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try clearing out your cache and cookies using the guide below?

http://en.support.wordpress.com/browser-issues/#clear-your-cache-and-cookies

Also, please make sure your browser is updated to the most recent version:

http://browsehappy.com

Then, finally try testing on browsers like Google Chrome and Firefox.

Also can you check if copying works in **`Text Mode`** or not ?

---

**Update** : May be there is some plugin thats causing the issue. Try disabling all the plugin at once. And enable them one by one to detect the plugin that's causing the issue.

---

**Update** : Change your theme to Wordpress default Twenty Seventeen theme and check if it solves your problem. If it does then there is some problem with the theme.

Comment: Hello, I am up to date with both Firefox and Chrome, so it doesn't seem to be that. I have tried clearing the cache/cookies, but that didn't affect it. I am pretty convinced that it is by a plugin.

Comment: Well in that case try disabling all the plugin at once. And enable them one by one to detect the plugin that's causing the issue.

Comment: By the way which WordPress version are you using ??

Comment: Using the latest version, which is 4.7.5. Will try disabling the plugins later today.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Ctrl-V (paste), after clicking in the edit window where you want things to be inserted?

How about a right-click, then paste?

Does 'paste' work outside of the WP editing screen (Notepad, for instance)?

Do you have the proper privileges (Author, when you are the Author of the post; Editor, or Admin)?

What if you create a new post? Can you paste there?

Are you sure there is something in your clipboard to paste?

See, more detail helps.....

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Rick, 

I have tried both right clicking, ctrl+v, using the TinyMCE toolbar for Pasting. I am the Admin and owner of the blog.

This is for all posts. When I make a new post, it is the same. Copy and paste still works on everything else. On comments on articles, it works. The only thing it doesn't work on is while I am writing posts.

There is definitely something on the clipboard. I have tested that multiple times.

Comment: Perhaps a plugin or your theme is getting in the way? If possible, change to a 'standard' theme (one of the 'twenty' themes) and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: I tried switching to Twenty Seventeen, but the bug still persists. Will try disabling some plugins next.

Comment: Strange problem. Does this also happen on another PC? Another browser? For weird problems, testing on another computer (or having a trusted friend try it on their system) might determine if the problem is local to your usually-used computer or is site-based. Running the site locally (rather than on the host) might also be something to try, assuming you have a local development environment.

Comment: Yep, I have tried doing all of the steps so far on multiple PCs and operating systems. I have basically arrived at the conclusion that this is being caused by a plugin, but I just want to make sure that it is by a plugin before making changes to the plugins/config of the site.

Comment: Well, a test for a bad plugin is quite easy (but it will affect your site if it is live). Just rename a plugin folder that is suspect, and try the paste thing again. If it is not that plugin, rename it back to it's original folder name. Good luck.

Comment: I've previously had this issue when something went wrong with a site migration and not all the files had been copied. So nothing to do with a plugin. If this sounds like it could have happened, I'd suggest doing a WP update - if this is the problem then the missing files will be replaced.